How to start a VM with a VF from a SRIOV pool if it fails due to a MAC setting?
I'm trying to run a KVM/QEMU VM under RHEL9 that uses a virtualized Infiniband card (VF) through SR-IOV from a pool of VFs.
I can specify a certain VF's PCI device with hostdev and that works just fine, however that requires hardcoding the PCI bus/slot/etc. into the VM XML sheet. That'd be a problem when migrating the VM to another server. So I'd rather define a network pool of VFs as described in this RH doc that would assign a free VF to a newly started VM automatically.
I did everything as described in the docs and the network pool of 8 VFs from a single IB card works like it should:
# virsh net-dumpxml IB-passthrough
<network>
  <name>IB-passthrough</name>
  <uuid>8dce28fa-97ea-43d4-a82b-5923fa1a2a4f</uuid>
  <forward mode='hostdev' managed='yes'>
    <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0xc1' slot='0x00' function='0x1'/>
    <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0xc1' slot='0x00' function='0x2'/>
    <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0xc1' slot='0x00' function='0x3'/>
    <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0xc1' slot='0x00' function='0x4'/>
    <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0xc1' slot='0x00' function='0x5'/>
    <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0xc1' slot='0x00' function='0x6'/>
    <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0xc1' slot='0x00' function='0x7'/>
    <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0xc1' slot='0x01' function='0x0'/>
  </forward>
</network>

I write the following entry into the VM's XML:
<interface type='network'>
  <source network='IB-passthrough'/>
</interface>

But after closing the XML editor, the entry gets automatically extended with mac and address entries:
<interface type='network'>
  <mac address='52:54:00:44:db:0d'/>
  <source network='IB-passthrough'/>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x07' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
</interface> 

Then the VM cannot be started since the MAC cannot be set:
# virsh start rhel9.2-testvm
    error: Failed to start domain 'rhel9.2-testvm'
    error: Cannot set interface MAC to 52:54:00:05:72:5c for ifname ibp193s0 vf 0: Operation not supported

Is there a way to omit that automatic MAC? Or the Interface MAC change? Or is there another problem that I'm missing?

I met the same error when running cmd:
virsh attach-interface vm1 hostdev 0000:81:00.2 --managed --persistent
error: Failed to attach interface
error: Cannot set interface MAC to 52:54:00:6f:a1:89 for ifname ibp129s0f0 vf 1: Operation not supported
This interface network pool seems doesn't work for IB(InfiniBand) cards it only works for ethernet cards, because setting a MAC to an IB card will fail. Only cant set node, policy and port.
$ ls  /sys/class/net/ibp129s0f0/device/sriov/0/
node  policy  port
Finally, I managed to add the VF device via cmd:
virt-xml vm1 --add-device --update --hostdev 0000:81:00.2
You need to treat the IB(InfiniBand) card as a normal PCI device, not an ethernet interface.
Refer to:
https://docs.nvidia.com/networking/display/mlnxofedv24101140lts/single+root+io+virtualization+(sr-iov)
https://enterprise-support.nvidia.com/s/article/HowTo-Configure-SR-IOV-for-ConnectX-4-ConnectX-5-ConnectX-6-with-KVM-Ethernet
https://docs.redhat.com/en/documentation/red_hat_enterprise_linux/9/html/configuring_and_managing_virtualization/managing-virtual-devices_configuring-and-managing-virtualization#assembly_managing-virtual-devices-using-the-cli_managing-virtual-devices
https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/virt-xml.1.html
